# denying access to sub folder by its real name using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i want to deny the user to acces the subfolder by its real name :
the real name is `"folder1"`
i want it to be accessed by an other name "`test`"
i already done that using this :

```
RewriteRule ^(test/)(.*)$ /folder1/$2 [L]
```

it works fine but it still can be accessed by its real name (site.com/folder1)
i already added  this after the previous line :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)(\/)(.*)$ error.php [L]
```

wich redirect any the user if he uses anything instead of the `"test"` but it also let him access it if he uses `"folder1"`.

please some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just turn off indexing on your site.

Add this to the top of you .htaccess file.

```
 Options -Indexes
 ErrorDocument 403 /
```

Comment: thx i tryed it somewhere else and it works i will debug my files and code and see if anything shows up

Comment: it worked for all the subfolders, but i can still access the subfolders that have the index.php file in them :/

Comment: Only thing I can think of is creating a password protected directory in .htaccess everything else will either end up in a redirect loop. Its impossible to completely hide your sub directory. One thing I do is choose names like 'S8AdusTeMebu' for my sub directories.

Comment: thank you for your asnwers , but i can't change the directories name and cant make them password protected, althought i tought of an walkaround i will make that possible by using PHP , by creating an index.php file that controls how the user enters the subfolder